# Why "getpixel(x,y)" can take negative value

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Hello i'm a beginner dev and i'm trying to find the color of a pixel with PILLOW and the function getpixel() and i don't understand why the function can take a negative value

```
def obtenir_couleur(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    x_true = x - map_canvas.winfo_x()

    pixel_color = mapCouleur.getpixel((x_true, y))
    print(pixel_color)
    

# Création de la fenêtre
window = Tk()

# Personnalisation de la fenêtre
window.title("Map interactive CH")
window.geometry("1920x1000")
window.minsize(720, 480)
window.config(background='#4065A4')


# Charger les images avec Pillow
mapCouleur = Image.open("images/MapColors.png")
print(mapCouleur.size)
mapChOri = PhotoImage(file="images/Map1.png")

# Création d'un widget Canvas pour afficher l'image
map_canvas = Canvas(window, width=mapChOri.width(), height=mapChOri.height(), bg='#4065A4', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
map_canvas.create_image(mapChOri.width()/2, mapChOri.height()/2, image=mapChOri)
map_canvas.pack(side=TOP)
print(mapChOri.width(), mapChOri.height())

# Création d'un label/text, explication de l'application
canton_label = Label(window, text="Cliquer sur la carte pour avoir le nom du canton", font=("Courrier", 32), bg='#4065A4', fg='white')
canton_label.pack(side=TOP)

cantonOutput = Entry(window, width=30, font=("Helvetica", 16), bg='#4065A4', fg='white')
cantonOutput.pack(side=TOP, pady=20)


window.bind("<Button-1>", obtenir_couleur)

#Affichage de la fenêtre
window.mainloop()
```

When i click on the left of my windows, i have a negative value to put in the function, and in don't understand why this works with a negative value.

I didn't find any answer in the documentation

Since my image size is 1132x800 I expect the function to not accept a negative value

Answer (score 1):

Python has a convention with list indexing of using negative numbers to indicate an offset from the end.  Pillow appears to use the same convention.  So for example, if you tried to access the pixel at (-1,-1) you'd actually get (1131,799).

If you use a negative number larger than the size of your image, you'll get an `IndexError` exception.